# iOS, after resizing button programming, it looses its outlet? not tappable?

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoa-touch, view

When user taps the upgrade button and successfully purchases my app, I move the positions of some of the controls.

Like so

```
CGRect f2 = AcountName.frame; 
f2.origin.y = 79; 
f2.size.height = 21; 
AcountName.frame = f2;
```

However AccountName, which is a button, can no longer be tapped. But when the view reloads it's fine.

It sounds like it's lost its outlet.

Do I need to refresh the button after moving / resizing it ?

Comment: what is the super view of the button..can you show it's `frame` property value??

Comment: try to change the bounds not the frame

Comment: @InderKumarRathore no I'm not able to see that property at runtime.

Comment: @iYaniv that doesn't change the position / size of the button though ?

Comment: @Jules it seems that your button is moving out of the superview's frame

Comment: Also check the IBAction connection of your button and file's owner.

Comment: @InderKumarRathore how do I ensure it doesn't move outside ?

Comment: make it super view's frame larger.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't exactly know why this worked, but this solved it for me.

```
[self.view bringSubviewToFront:AccountName];
```